# Can I Use Two RAMS of Different Size in Laptop?

Tags: memory

Today i planned to Play GTA V on my PC. So i require some Specs for My pc. I have computer/laptop of 2gb RAM that is not enough to play that game. So decided to buys some 4gb RAM for my laptop. Can i Add 2gb RAM and 4gb RAM to make it 2+4=6GB RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can use two SODIMMS of different capacity.   Case in point, my MSI GL62 shipped with 12GB of ram, an 8GB and a 4GB SODIMM.  The same goes for a Desktop with full length DIMMS.